# remover webservice de projecto con eclipse

Tags: java, webservice, eclipse

Hola lo que pasa es que actualmente tengo que cambiar en mi proyecto de java de un webservice a otro, lo que quiero saber es si ¿alguien sabe la forma de eliminar el webservice anterior para poder agregar el nuevo que me pueda explicar?

nota: yo uso eclipse

de antemano gracias y que alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: Depende de la herramienta que hayas usado para consumir el web service. Normalmente, si quieres realmente eliminar su consumo, borra las clases que invocan al servicio web y las clases asociadas al request y response de eso.

Comment: de echo lo agregue con eclipse por eso quiero saber si no hay una forma de eliminarlo con el mismo eclipse ya que no quiero borrar algo que no sea ya que el webservice cambio a otro.

Comment: No, Eclipse no borra esos archivos. En realidad Eclipse no los crea, delega la creación a un framework como Axis2.

Comment: Con esto, surge mi duda: ¿realmente necesitas borrar el consumo del web service de raíz, eliminando las clases? En realidad, basta con dejar de invocar el método que llama al web service y listo.

Comment: Bueno lo que pasa es que pensé en dejar de invocar el webservice anterior y luego ir depurando poco a poco pero al agregar el nuevo webservice creo que se mezclo ya que comparten algunos nombres de funciones  con el anterior y ahora no tengo ninguno de los dos queria borrarlos y agregarlos de nuevo

Comment: Bueno, revisa mi primer comentario entonces :)